# How to change Microsoft Visio relation line color?

Tags: microsoft-visio

So I've just been given an entity diagram in Microsoft's Visio and it has hundreds of tables.

Is there any way to change the line color so I can easily track down the table it's linked to? As of right now seeing a bunch of black makes it pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on the version of Visio you are using. In 2010 professional, if you r-click on an arrow, select format then line, there is a color option in that dialog

[image]